# how do I decode json in a generic function

Tags: json, templates, go

How do I do something like this (assuming T is a template like in C++, C#, Java etc...) in golang:

```
func DecodeFormToJson(r *http.Request, t *T) err error {
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
    err = decoder.Decode(&t)
    return 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply using an `interface{}` which is what [`Decoder.Decode`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder.Decode) uses anyway, for [example](http://play.golang.org/p/b1YAGU6C_b):

```
func proxyDecode(r io.Reader, i interface{}) error {
    dec := json.NewDecoder(r)
    return dec.Decode(i)
}
```